# Generate URL from sql tables data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, common-table-expression

Consider the folowing tables:

`EntityPictures` Table:

```
Id  EntityId    PictureId  EntityType
1     66              1     Product
```

`Pictures` Table

```
Id  MimeType    SeoFilename  AltAttribute   TitleAttribute  
1   image/png   seoFilename1 altAttribute1  titleAttribute1 
2   image/png       seox         altx               titlex
```

I want to write a query to print the list of `Products` with generated `PictureUrl` column, based on `imagesize` input

psudo code:

```
@imageSizes={100,200}
foreach(imagesize in @imageSizes)
    select *,PictureUrl from products where Id=@id
```

image size is not a column of any table, it just used for generate urls

Expected result:

```
Id   PictureUrl
10  http://localhost/content/images/thumbs/1_seoFilename1_100.png
11  http://localhost/content/images/thumbs/1_seoFilename1_200.png
```

**Update**

in `1_seoFilename1_200.png`, 1 is Picture Id, 100 and 200 is generated based on where clause. if we had only where  imagesize=100 , the expected result will be

```
Id   PictureUrl
10  http://localhost/content/images/thumbs/1_seoFilename1_100.png
```

And `@id` is `EntityId` in `EntityPictures` table.

Comment: would you please share your Products table structure?

Comment: Product table is not matter, It has only Id and Name column.

Comment: but what's about rest of your where clause?

Comment: from where you are getting your url value `http://localhost/content/images/thumbs/`

Comment: where're column `imagesize` and `imagesize` ?

Comment: I want to generate 2 url based on where clause

Comment: how to do you get imagesize based on your existing rows then?

Comment: each picture can has any number of imagesize, it's auto generated. and it's not persist.

Comment: so why do you need WHERE for imagesize when its auto generated?

Comment: because image size is a input from user, to generate url with that size

Comment: so its a parameter, not a condition

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: so you are passing image size one by one in parameter like `100` for once and then `200` or passing this imagesize in some other format, since there are 2 values mentioned by you in query.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your query.

to extract `png` from `image/png`, use this one

```
substring(pt.MimeType, charindex('/', pt.MimeType, 1) + 1, 
        len(pt.MimeType) - 1)
```

Complete query (for single parameter)

```
select ep.Id,
    concat('http://localhost/content/images/thumbs/'
      , ep.Id, '_', pt.SeoFilename, '_', @imgSize, '.', 
      substring(pt.MimeType, charindex('/', pt.MimeType, 1) + 1, 
        len(pt.MimeType) - 1)
    ) as PictureURL
from EntityPictures ep 
join Pictures pt on pt.Id= ep.EntityId
where ep.Id=@id
```

To generate N number of rows you can use CTE.

```
    with MultiRows (RowNum, ImageSize) as (      
       select 1 as RowNum, 100 AS ImageSize
       union all          
       select a.RowNum + 1, a.ImageSize + 100 AS ImageSize
       from   MultiRows a
       where  a.RowNum < 2
    )
    select t1.Id,  
            concat('http://localhost/content/images/thumbs/'
              , t1.Id, '_', t1.SeoFilename, '_', m.ImageSize, '.', 
              substring(t1.MimeType, charindex('/', t1.MimeType, 1) + 1, 
                len(t1.MimeType) - 1)
            ) as PictureURL 
    from  MultiRows m
    left join (
                select row_number() over (order by ep.id) as rn, ep.Id, pt.SeoFilename, pt.MimeType
                    from EntityPictures ep 
                join Pictures pt on pt.Id= ep.EntityId
                where ep.Id=@id 
            ) t1 on m.ROwNum = t1.rn;
    go
```

Comment: EntityId is not column of Pictures table

Comment: imagesize is not a column of any table, its only input for generate urls

Comment: something's missing on the requirement.

Comment: please update your answer to use imagesize as a parameter, (we can have array of sizes)

Comment: thank you, this works, but I want to select *,imageUrl from products table and imageSizes are array of int

Comment: you can use CTE if you want to generate N number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sample date:

```
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
        [Id] [int] NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityPictures](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [EntityId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [PictureId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [DisplayOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
        [IsDefault] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [EntityType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_EntityPictures] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pictures](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [PictureBinary] [varbinary](max) NULL,
        [MimeType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [SeoFilename] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [AltAttribute] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [TitleAttribute] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [IsNew] [bit] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Pictures] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (66, N'P1')
    INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (67, N'P2')
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EntityPictures] ON 

    INSERT [dbo].[EntityPictures] ([Id], [EntityId], [PictureId], [DisplayOrder], [IsDefault], [EntityType]) VALUES (1, 66, 1, 0, 0, N'Product')
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EntityPictures] OFF
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Pictures] ON 

    INSERT [dbo].[Pictures] ([Id], [PictureBinary], [MimeType], [SeoFilename], [AltAttribute], [TitleAttribute], [IsNew]) VALUES (1, 0x, N'image/png', N'seoFilename1', N'altAttribute1', N'titleAttribute1', 0)
    INSERT [dbo].[Pictures] ([Id], [PictureBinary], [MimeType], [SeoFilename], [AltAttribute], [TitleAttribute], [IsNew]) VALUES (2, 0x, N'image/png', N'seoFilenameoo', N'altAttributeoo', N'titleAttributeoo', 0)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Pictures] OFF
```

My solution based on [metal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57686146/3427324) solution:

```
declare @listOfIDs table (id int);
insert @listOfIDs(id) values(100),(200);    
declare @id int=66;
declare @baseUrl varchar(256)='http://localhost/content/images/thumbs/';

    select id,name,PictureURL from (select * from products p
    join (select ep.EntityId,
        concat(@baseUrl
          , ep.Id, '_', pt.SeoFilename, '_', l.id, '.', 
          substring(pt.MimeType, charindex('/', pt.MimeType, 1) + 1, 
            len(pt.MimeType) - 1)
        ) as PictureURL
    from dbo.EntityPictures ep 
    join dbo.Pictures pt on pt.Id= ep.PictureId
    right join @listOfIDs l on l.id=l.id 
    ) t on 1=1) x
    where x.Id=@id
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I presume your Picture table has a column that specifies the 'imagesize'?

if so, please try the following:

`SELECT ('http://localhost/content/images/thumbs/66_'+seoFilename1+'_'+imagesize+'.png') AS PictureUrl
FROM Pictures
WHERE Id = @id AND (imagesize = 100 or imagesize = 200)`

Pleas also note, 'localhost' would have to be changed once going into production.

Comment: localhost is constant, but seofilename is in the Pictures table

Comment: and in what table is your `imagefilesize` column?

Comment: it's not exist, I'd like to generate it, based on where clause

Comment: a `WHERE` clause is there to evaluate a user's desired outcome with the resultset of your query (condition), if `imagefilesize` does not exist in any table, you can not use it in your `WHERE` clause

please familiarize with SQL before posting questions.